# Clarification for syntax of conditional operator in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is the code I'm using . I want to know that the syntax of the conditional operator is correct or not?

```
<Col span={12}>
                    <FormItem label="Admin User Name">
                      {getFieldDecorator('username', {
                        initialValue: this.state.userName,
                        rules: [{
                          required: this.props.userNameExist === true ? {message: 'Please Input user name!'} : {message: 'User Name already Exists!'}
                        }],
                      })(
                        <Input name="userName" placeholder="Admin UserName"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
                            this.handleChange(e)
                          }}
                        />
                      )}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
```

This is the line of code that I want to know whether the syntax is right or not.

```
this.props.userNameExist === true ? {message: 'Please Input user name!'} : {message: 'User Name already Exists!'}
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. Is it giving you any errors?

Comment: No errors I just wanted to make sure it

Comment: The code of mine didn't worked. It was logical error>

Comment: I wanted to check whether it's due to the syntax

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the syntax.